# Removing zeros after comma based on maximum consequent zeros

Tags: javascript, string, loops, nested-loops

I have a page with a grid where user's numbers get saved. It has a following pattern - every number ends with 3 digits after comma. It doesn't look nice, when for example user's input is

```
123,450
123,670
123,890
```

It's much better to have just 2 numbers after comma, because last `0` is absolutely meaningless and redundant.

The way it still should have 3 digits is only if at least one element in an array doesn't end up with `0`

For example:

```
123,455
123,450
123,560
```

In this case 1st element of the array has the last digit not equal to `0` and hence all the elements should have 3 digits. The same story with 2 or 1 zeros

Zeros are redundant:

```
123,30
123,40
123,50
```

Zeros are necessary:

```
123,35
123,40
123,50
```

The question is how can I implement it programatically? I've started like this:

```
var zeros2Remove = 0;
numInArray.forEach(function(item, index, numInArray) 
{
    var threeDigitsAfterComma = item.substring(item.indexOf(',') + 1);

    for(var j = 2; j <= 0; j--) 
    {
        if(threeDigitsAfterComma[j] == 0) 
        {
            zeros2Remove =+ 1;
        } 
        else //have no idea what to do..
    }   
})
```

Well in my implementation I don't know how to do it since I have to iterate through every element but break it if at least 1 number has a last digit equal to zero.. In order to do that I have to break outer loop, but don't know how and I'm absolutely sure that I don't have to...

Comment: What happens if all the strings are of the form `"123,000"`?

Comment: Only 1 zero is after the comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code what you are looking for exactly , please manipulate numbers and see the changes :

```js
var arr = ["111.3030", "2232.0022", "3.001000", "4","558.0200","55.00003000000"];
var map = arr.map(function(a) {
  if (a % 1 === 0) {
    var res = "1";
  } else {
    var lastNumman = a.toString().split('').pop();
    if (lastNumman == 0) {
      var m = parseFloat(a);
      var res = (m + "").split(".")[1].length;
    } else {
      var m = a.split(".")[1].length;
      var res = m;
    }
  }

  return res;

})
var maxNum = map.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b);
});

arr.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(Number.parseFloat(el).toFixed(maxNum));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code did the trick! But could you please explain more details about this solution and break down the code, if you would. I want to grasp it by myself. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution might seem a little cumbersome but it should work for all possible scenarios. It should be easy enough to make always return a minimal number of decimals places/leading zeros.

I hope it helps.

```js
// Define any array
const firstArray = [
  '123,4350',
  '123,64470',
  '123,8112390',
]

const oneOfOfYourArrays = [
  '123,30',
  '123,40',
  '123,50',
]

// Converts 123,45 to 123.45
function stringNumberToFloat(stringNumber) {
  return parseFloat(stringNumber.replace(',', '.'))
}

// For 123.45 you get 2
function getNumberOfDecimals(number) {
  return number.split('.')[1].length;
}

// This is a hacky way how to remove traling zeros
function removeTralingZeros(stringNumber) {
  return stringNumberToFloat(stringNumber).toString()
}

// Sorts numbers in array by number of their decimals
function byNumberOfValidDecimals(a, b) {
  const decimalsA = getNumberOfDecimals(a)
  const decimalsB = getNumberOfDecimals(b)
  return decimalsB - decimalsA
}

// THIS IS THE FINAL SOLUTION
function normalizeDecimalPlaces(targetArray) {
  const processedArray = targetArray
  .map(removeTralingZeros) // We want to remove trailing zeros
  .sort(byNumberOfValidDecimals) // Sort from highest to lowest by number of valid decimals

  const maxNumberOfDecimals = processedArray[0].split('.')[1].length

  return targetArray.map((stringNumber) => stringNumberToFloat(stringNumber).toFixed(maxNumberOfDecimals))
}

console.log('normalizedFirstArray', normalizeDecimalPlaces(firstArray))

console.log('normalizedOneOfOfYourArrays', normalizeDecimalPlaces(oneOfOfYourArrays))
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach),

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool. Use a plain loop or [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead.

If you convert your `forEach` loop to a `for` loop, you can break out of it with a label and [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement:

```js
// unrelated example
let i;
let j;
outerLoop:
for (i = 2; i < 100; ++i) {
  innerLoop:
  for (j = 2; j < 100; ++j) {
    // brute-force prime factorization
    if (i * j === 2183) { break outerLoop; }
  }
}
console.log(i, j);
```

I gave you an unrelated example because your problem doesn't need nested loops at all. You can find the number of trailing zeroes in a string with a regular expression:

```
function getTrailingZeroes (str) {
  return str.match(/0{0,2}$/)[0].length;
}
```

[`str.match(/0{0,2}$/)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) finds between 0 and 2 zeroes at the end of `str` and returns them as a string in a one-element array. The length of that string is the number of characters you can remove from `str`. You can make one pass over your array of number-strings, breaking out when necessary, and use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as a separate truncation loop:

```
function getShortenedNumbers (numInArray) {
  let zeroesToRemove = Infinity;
  for (const str of numInArray) {
    let candidate = getTrailingZeroes(str);
    zeroesToRemove = Math.min(zeroesToRemove, candidate);
    if (zeroesToRemove === 0) break;
  }

  return numInArray.map(str => str.substring(0, str.length - zeroesToRemove);
}
```

All together:

```js
function getTrailingZeroes (str) {
  return str.match(/0{0,2}$/)[0].length;
}

function getShortenedNumbers (numInArray) {
  let zeroesToRemove = Infinity;
  for (const str of numInArray) {
    let candidate = getTrailingZeroes(str);
    zeroesToRemove = Math.min(zeroesToRemove, candidate);
    if (zeroesToRemove === 0) break;
  }

  return numInArray.map(str => str.substring(0, str.length - zeroesToRemove));
}

console.log(getShortenedNumbers(['123,450', '123,670', '123,890']));
console.log(getShortenedNumbers(['123,455', '123,450', '123,560']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function removeZeros(group) {
    var maxLength = 0;
  var newGroup = [];
    for(var x in group) {
    var str = group[x].toString().split('.')[1];
    if(str.length > maxLength) maxLength = str.length;
  }

  for(var y in group) {
    var str = group[y].toString();
    var substr = str.split('.')[1];
    if(substr.length < maxLength) {
        for(var i = 0; i < (maxLength - substr.length); i++) 
        str += '0';
    } 
    newGroup.push(str); 
  }

  return newGroup;
}
```

Try it on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32sdvzn1/1/

My script checks the length of every number decimal part, remember that JavaScript removes the last zeros in a decimal number, so 3.10 would be 3.1, so the length is less when there is a number with zeros in the end, in this case we just add a zero to the number.

#### Update

I've updated the script, the new version adds as much zeros as the different between the max decimal length and the decimal length of the analyzed number.

#### Example

We have: *3.11*, *3.1423*, *3.1*

The max length would be: **4** (1423)

maxLenght (4)  - length of .11 (2)  = 2

We add 2 zeros to 3.11, that will become 3.1100

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start out assuming you will remove two extra zeros, and loop through your array looking for digits in the last two places. With the commas, I'm assuming your numArray elements are strings, all starting with the same length.

```
var numArray = ['123,000', '456,100', '789,110'];

var removeTwo = true, removeOne = true;
for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
    if (numArray[i][6] !== '0') { removeTwo = false; removeOne = false; }
    if (numArray[i][5] !== '0') { removeTwo = false; }
}

// now loop to do the actual removal
for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
    if (removeTwo) {
        numArray[i] = numArray[i].substr(0, 5);
    } else if (removeOne) {
        numArray[i] = numArray[i].substr(0, 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, they are not the same. They all end with same length(3). That's why I've splitted it with `item.substring(item.indexOf(',') + 1);`